# Sort firebase data in descending order using negative timestamp

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

above is a screenshot of my firebase database. i am trying to sort firebase data in descending order using negative timestamp. I 'm using the following command:

```
  const feedRef = database.ref('ducks')
  feedRef.orderByChild('timestamp').on('value', (snapshot, error) => {
    const feed = snapshot.val()})
```

i keep getting the feed in the same order as the database not in the descending order like i want.I think its not working because ducks endpoint doesnt have a child name timestamp
how would i achieve this? Do the push generated keys have timestamp data ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you call `.val()` on a snapshot, it gets converted into a JSON object. And the keys in a JavaScript object are by definition unordered (although many implementations will iterate the keys in lexicographical order).

If you run a query on the Firebase Database, you must ensure you don't convert it to JSON before you get the items in the right order. In your case, by using [`DataSnapshot.forEach()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#forEach):

```
const feedRef = database.ref('ducks')
var feed = [];
feedRef.orderByChild('timestamp').on('value', (snapshot, error) => {
    snapshot.forEach((duckSnap) => {
        const duck = duckSnap.val()
        console.log(duckSnap.key+'='+duck.name);
        feed.push(duck);
    });
    console.log(feed);
});
```

Comment: I may be wrong but shouldn't that be duckSnap.val(). also as i iterate over snapshot i should build another object by pushing data to it in the order i want?

Comment: I tried the following and still the order is still ascending  ``database.ref('ducks').orderByChild('timestamp').on('value', (snapshot, error) => {
    let feed = {}
    snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
      feed[childSnapshot.key] = childSnapshot.val()
    })
    console.log('ducks feed: ', feed)``

Comment: The `snapshot.forEach()` will execute in the correct order.. But JSON is unordered. So if you put the ducks into `feed` based on their `childSnapshot.key`, the resulting `feed` object will be unordered again. I've expanded my answer to include a sample of that.

Comment: @jasan: inside the loop it should indeed use `duckSnap`. Thanks for pointing that out, I fixed it now (I don't know why your edit was rejects in review).