# firebase -> date order reverse

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently making an app using Firebase.

It is one of those bulletin boards that can be seen anywhere on the web.

But there was one problem.

This is a matter of date sorting.

I want to look at the recent date first, but I always see only the data I created first.

```
postRef.orderByChild('createData').startAt(reverseDate).limitToFirst(1).on('child_added',(data)=>{
    console.log(data.val().name + data.val().createData);
})
```

result - >`hello1496941142093`

My firebase tree[image]

My code is the same as above.

How can I check my recent posts first?

How Do I order reverse of firebase database?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The Firebase Database will always return results in ascending order. There is no way to reverse them.

There are two common workaround for this:

1. Let the database do the filtering, but then reverse the results client-side.
2. Add an inverted value to the database, and use that for querying.

These options have been covered quite a few times before. So instead of repeating, I'll give a list of previous answers:

- [Display posts in descending posted order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25611356/display-posts-in-descending-posted-order)
- [Sort firebase data in descending order using negative timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38548406/sort-firebase-data-in-descending-order-using-negative-timestamp)
- [firebase sort reverse order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43252794/firebase-sort-reverse-order)
- [Is it possible to reverse a Firebase list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40293539/is-it-possible-to-reverse-a-firebase-list)
- many more from this list: https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+firebase+reverse%20sort%20javascript

Comment: Thank you.. first i don't understand 0 - new Date().Getitme() insert to in firebase in database.. but not i understand.. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

You can simply make a function to reverse the object and then traversing it.

```
function reverseObject(object) {
    var newObject = {};
    var keys = [];

    for (var key in object) {
        keys.push(key);
    }

    for (var i = keys.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var value = object[keys[i]];
        newObject[keys[i]]= value;
    }       

    return newObject;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to display it in the front end, I suggest that after you retrieve the data, use the `reverse()` function of JavaScript.

Example:

```
let result = postRef
  .orderByChild("createData")
  .startAt(reverseDate)
  .limitToFirst(1)
  .on("child_added", data => {
    console.log(data.val().name + data.val().createData);
  });

result.reverse();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved it:
First I made a query in my service where I filter by date in milliseconds:

```
 getImages (): Observable<Image[]> {
this.imageCollection = this.asf.collection<Image>('/images', ref => ref.orderBy('time').startAt(1528445969388).endAt(9999999999999));
this.images = this.imageCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
  map(actions => actions.map(a => {
    const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Image;
    const id = a.payload.doc.id;
    return { id, ...data };
  }))
);
return this.images;
```

}

Then to get the newest date first I added this to my component where I call the method from my service:

```
let date = new Date;
let time = 9999999999999 - date.getTime();
console.log(time);
```

I pass the time let as the date. Since a newer date will be a bigger number to deduct from the 9999999999999, the newest date will turn up first in my query inside my service.

Hope this solved it for you

Answer (score 0):

Ive ended changing how I create my list on the frontend part.

was

```
posts.add(post);
```

changed to

```
posts.insert(0, post);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a method where you save the same or alternate child with a negative value and then parse it.

```
postRef.orderByChild('createData').orderByChild('createData').on('child_added',(data)=>{
console.log(data.val().name + data.val().createData);})
```

Answer (score 0):

Far more easier is just use Swift's `reversed()`:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1690025-reversed
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/reversedcollection

```
let decodedIds = try DTDecoder().decode([String].self, from: value)
// we reverse it, because we want most recent orders at the top
let reversedDecodedIds = decodedIds.reversed().map {$0}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
orderBy("timestamp", "desc")
```

I think you can give a second argument name "desc".
It worked for me