# Get the Positive Value of a "Negative" Timestamp

Tags: javascript, date, time

Simple Date question here, but I can't seem to find a simple answer.

I am storing the 'negative' value of a timestamp in my database like so (they are stored as numbers, not strings):

```
user-1
  --date: -1495255666921
user-2
  --date: -1495255666341
```

I do this for sorting purposes, but that's a separate topic.

When it comes time to read these dates under each user, I want to get the 'positive' version of the timestamp.

I know I can `toString()` the date, check for the `-` character, remove it, then convert it back to a `Date()` (which I then have to run through *another* function), but that seems inefficient when sending thousands of records back to the client.

Is there a magical way I can **poof** - get rid of that `-` *and* maintain it's datatype as `timestamp` programatically? Any input or recommendation is appreciated!

**UPDATE** - Since multiple people have mentioned, this is is the ['bigger' issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44442816/firebase-date-order-reverse) I'm dealing with and why I've chosen this sorting method

Comment: Have you tried [Math.abs()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/abs)?

Comment: Why do you have "negative" timestamps in the first place?  AFAIK if you are dealing with UNIX timestamps, they should only be positive.

Comment: Just multiply by `-1`, or use unary `-`, if you know that your numbers are always negative?

Comment: "*I do this for sorting purposes, but that's a separate topic.*" - no, it's the cause of your problem. For sorting purposes, you should adjust the sorting method, *not the data*.

Comment: @PHPglue I'm trying to avoid converting between strings/integers, Math.abs() returns an integer which I'd then have to convert & yadda yadda

Comment: @Bergi appreciate the feedback, but I put this method in place to alleviate an even bigger headache. You can message me if you'd like to know more

Comment: Bergi is so, so, right. Perfect advice. Don't hack up your data like this. Besides, negative timestamps are perfectly fine and they refer to dates before January 1, 1970 UTC, so this might be a cause for confusion

Comment: @RayToal understood, I was against this very method from the start but lets assume its staying this way yeah? :D

Comment: @KuraiBankusu You might want to [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) about how to fix this "headache" that is your actual problem.

Comment: Your timestamps are stored as strings? If so, then you should make this clear in your question. Add double quotes around your timestamp values. As for the solution if this is the case, use the `substring` method to exclude the first character.

Comment: @KuraiBankusu no problem, just reiterating a good suggestion. `Math.abs()` is your friend for now!

Comment: @B.Fleming they are stored as actual timestamps prefixed with the '-', so I can't utilize `substring()` without converting it first.

Comment: @Bergi see my update on the post

Comment: I don't see a "timestamp" type .. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types so it must be a number ?

Comment: `Math.abs(parseInt(yourStringNumberHere))`

Comment: @Slai there is Date and time, if the '-' I prefix to the date converts it to a number I'm not sure yet

Comment: yes if you prefix JavaScript Date with a sign it's converted to a number, so either use Math.abs(value) or negate it with -value

Comment: @Slai looks like that's the only way to go then. Thank you!

Comment: @KuraiBankusu Thanks, that's pretty horrible. Or was, at least, since they seem to have fixed it and you now can [get the most recent entries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25647342/1048572) without trickery. In any case, what code are you using to negate the timestamp in the first place? You will need to do the inverse of that to get the original timestamp back.