# firebase use orderByChild on child's child's value

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I am building an app with react-native. I would like to sort the `chatList` by the `createdAt` value in descending order.

Here is my structure:

```
{
   "chatList": {
       "L3RDhCUvTVBk--KKgCl" : {
           "lastMessage": {
               "createdAt": 1516638900725
           }
       },
       "L3RDhCUvTVBk--KKgC1" : {
           "lastMessage": {
               "createdAt": 1516638920725
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Also, do I need to index this structure?

Answer (score 1):

If your last message always at `lastMessage/createdAt` under the chat, (e.g. `/chatList/*/lastMessage/createdAt`) then you can query the chat lists with:

```
firebase.database.reference("chatList").orderByChild("lastMessage/createdAt")
```

You can't get then in descending order though. So you'll either have to reverse the results in the client, or store an inverted timestamp. See my answer here for more on that: [firebase -> date order reverse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44442816/firebase-date-order-reverse)

If the `lastMessage` is actually dynamic (so different for each child under `chatList`), then unfortunately you can't get the result from your current structure and you'll need to augment your data to allow the query.

If you want to get a list of chats ordered by their last update date, then you'll need to store precisely that in your database: a list of chats and their last update date.

```
{
  "chatUpdates": {
    "L3RDhCUvTVBk--KKgCl": 1516638900725
    "L3RDhCUvTVBk--KKgC1": 1516638920725
  }
}
```

This is an *additional* data structure, purely to allow your use-case. So now you'll need to update both `chatList` and `chatUpdates` when a message is added. To learn more about efficient ways to do that, see [How to write denormalized data in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30693785/how-to-write-denormalized-data-in-firebase)

Some related questions:

- [Firebase Query Double Nested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207059/firebase-query-double-nested)
- [Firebase query if child of child contains a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value)

Comment: Is this syntax for nested properties on ordering formally documented anywhere?  If not, that's kind of a doc bug.

Comment: It was introduced at the same time as multi-location updates: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/09/introducing-multi-location-updates-and_86.html and present in the old docs: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-queries. But it's indeed completely missing from the docs today, so... yeah.... time to [file a bug report](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).

Comment: I have tried to use `firebase.database.reference("chatList").orderByChild("lastMessage/createdAt")`. However, the response is not sorted

Comment: Is there something else I need to do to really sort the `chatList`? like `.indexOn`, etc.

Comment: Please update your question to show the code that you've tried, including how you handle the snapshot.