# How to retrieve data from Firebase real-time database in reverse order in web

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to retrieve the data from Firebase real-time database in reverse order in the web for example blogs, the last blog will show first.

Comment: Results are always returned from Firebase in ascending order. That means that you'll either have to reverse the results client-side, or store a property with an inverted value. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44442816/firebase-date-order-reverse/44443042#44443042

Answer (score 0):

Read the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data) to add index on your database.