# Order async objects by date

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2, angular-pipe

I have Angular 5 + Firebase app, where I get items from a Firebase list and set them into a view with *ngFor.

```
  <a routerLink="post/{{post.url}}" *ngFor="let post of (posts | async)">
     <h2>{{ post?.title }}</h2>
     <span>{{ post?.date }}</span>
  </a>
```

Every item I have a "Date" field in the format "dd.mm.yyyy". How can I set them into component view sorted by date (from newest to older)?

How can I get posts from Firebase:

```
  getPosts(): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.db.list('posts').snapshotChanges().map(changes => {
      return changes.map(c => ({
        key: c.payload.key,
        ...c.payload.val() }));
    });
  }
```

Comment: You can probably sort the `posts` when you get them. Can we see the code for that?

Comment: As @ConnorsFan says you  can query from firebase and get the sorted data, if not, you can also map over the observable and sort in the service before subscribe in the template

Comment: @ConnorsFan i add code to question

Comment: I don't know firebase but you can try this syntax: `this.db.list('posts', { query: { orderByChild: 'date' } }).map((arr) => { return arr.reverse(); }).snapshotChanges()...`. There may be a way to specify "desc" with `orderByChild`; if so, the call to `reverse()` would not be necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the dates as `"dd.mm.yyyy"`, which is a date format that is inherently hard to sort. With that format, you'll have to do sorting/filtering on the client.

If you store the dates in an ISO-8859 format (e.g. `yyyy-mm-dd`) you can let Firebase handle the sorting/filtering with:

```
this.db.list('posts', ref => ref.orderByChild('date'))
```

See also the [AngularFire2 documentation on queries](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/querying-lists.md).

Note that this will only sort the items in *ascending* order though, so from oldest to newest. If you want them descending you'll either have to reverse in the client, or store an inverted value. In the latter case I'd recommend storing an inverted timestamp instead of a string, e.g.

```
"negativeTimestamp": -1523753371440
```

For more on this, see the links in my answer to [firebase -> date order reverse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44442816/firebase-date-order-reverse/44443042#44443042)