# Firebase query in desc order based on timestamp

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I am having trouble returning an array of objects in desc order from firebase and javascript with react native. I am essentially "joining" two firebase parents and then pushing them into an array.

```
async loadChats(userId){

 this.chatIdRef = firebase.database().ref("members");
 this.chatIdRef.off();
 this.chatsRef = firebase.database().ref("chats");
 this.chatsRef.off();

 items = [];
 this.chatIdRef.child(userId).on('child_added', snap => {
 this.chatsRef.child(snap.key).startAt().on('value', snapshot => {

    items.push({
      receiverId: snap.val().userId,
      timeStamp: snapshot.val().createdAt,
      name: snap.val().userName,
      key: snapshot.key
    });

  this.setState({
    dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(items)
  });

  });
 });
}
```

I have tried using "orderByChild('createdAt')" in my query but no luck.

Comment: Firebase Database queries return items in ascending order. There is no built-in operator to reverse that order. You can either reverse the results client-side, or add a property with an inverted value (i.e. -1 * timestamp) to your data model.

Comment: Previous questions covering this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25611356, https://stackoverflow.com/q/38548406, https://stackoverflow.com/q/34156996, or any of [the results in this list](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-database%5D+descending).

Comment: Using a negative timestamp works perfectly. Thanks

Comment: I used .reverse to order the elements from newest to oldest.

Answer (score 0):

From the Firebase docs, queries with `orderByChild` return lists in the following order :-

> Children with a null value for the specified child key come first.
>
> Children with a value of false for the specified child key come next. If multiple children have a value of false, they are sorted lexicographically by key.
>
> Children with a value of true for the specified child key come next. If multiple children have a value of true, they are sorted lexicographically by key.
>
> Children with a numeric value come next, sorted in ascending order. If multiple children have the same numerical value for the specified child node, they are sorted by key.
>
> Strings come after numbers and are sorted lexicographically in ascending order. If multiple children have the same value for the specified child node, they are ordered lexicographically by key.
>
> Objects come last and are sorted lexicographically by key in ascending order.

So, from the above, please note that when your data has numerical values, it is returned in *ascending* order. Now that you know the order in which the data will be retrieved, you can just make changes to your client app to show the data in reverse ( in descending order ). Maybe reverse your list or something similar?