# Using orderByChild Firebase to get most recent posts

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to order my query based on the 'order_date' value. Unfortunately, it is returning them in the reverse order (oldest orders first). I am also trying to accomplish this with pagination. This is my current query.

```
var orders = fbdatabase.ref('orders').orderByChild('order_date');
orders.on('value', function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.val())
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to query in reverse order with Firebase. You'll need to use `limitToLast`:

```
var orders = fbdatabase.ref('orders')
  .orderByChild('order_date')
  .limitToLast(20);

orders.on('value', function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.val().reverse());
});
```

Alternatively, you could store an additional field like `order_date_desc` that uses a negative value (assuming timestamp).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Michael's answer, you're also not retaining the order in your callback. It's important to loop over the snapshot using `snapshot.forEach()` before calling `.val()`:

```
var orders = fbdatabase.ref('orders').orderByChild('inverted_order_date');
orders.on('value', function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(order) {
    console.log(order.val())
  });
});
```

See

- [Firebase Data Desc Sorting in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34156996/firebase-data-desc-sorting-in-android/34158197#34158197)
- [Display posts in descending posted order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25611356/display-posts-in-descending-posted-order/25613337#25613337)
- [Sort firebase data in descending order using negative timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38548406/sort-firebase-data-in-descending-order-using-negative-timestamp/38548568#38548568)